# Automation Error: Object has Disconnected from Clients on Document.Close

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro that goes through an inbox, opens up word documents, and uploads the info to an access database, and it works well almost all the time. However a very small percentage of the word documents cause "Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients" to pop up when I close the word document. I can't figure out what is different about the documents that cause the error for the life of me, and I'm wondering what the issue could be. It's at most 1% of the documents that cause this error, but this code gets run fairly often so its a pain. Below is my code with the line that causes the error starred.

```
Sub Updatexxx()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objMail As Object
Dim objAttach As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("xxx")
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

For Each objMail In objFolder.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
    For Each objAttach In objMail.Attachments
        strPath = "C:\TEMP\" & objAttach.FileName
        If InStr(strPath, ".doc") <> 0 Then
            objAttach.SaveAsFile (strPath)
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strPath, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
            wdDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
            wdDoc.UnProtect "xxx"
            With wdDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "xxx"
                .Execute
                If .Found = True Then
                    If wdDoc.FormFields(56).Result = 0 Then wdApp.Run ("xxx")
                Else:
                    If wdDoc.FormFields(66).Result = 0 Then wdApp.Run ("xxx")
                End If
            End With
        End If
        **wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False**
        Kill strPath
    Next objAttach
    objMail.UnRead = False
Next objMail
wdApp.Quit
End Sub
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Not sure whether this is an error only in the code you posted here, but it seems not correct that the call to `wdDoc.Close` is outside the if statement and the corresponding call opening the document is inside the if. Could the 1% of failing documents be non-Word document?

Comment: I moved wdDoc.Close and Kill strPath inside the if statement and its working now! They were all word documents, so I have no idea why those documents in particular were causing an error while others weren't.

Comment: A couple of other points about your code: 1) THere should not be a colon (:) after `Else`; 2) Since this is running from outside of Word it would be good practise to set the Word objects to `Nothing` once they're no longer needed. The error message you had *can* come from not doing this (although it apparently wasn't the case in this instance). So: `Set wdDoc = Nothing` following `wdDoc.Close` and `Set wdApp = Nothing` following `wdApp.Quit`.